# Is there a way to login and logout user after installation on ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a playbook to install tableau server but there is a part where you need to logout and login the user after the installation so you can proceed with the next steps of installation. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is for a remote system, so the answer is yes.

You can add the following meta in a task file (taken from the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html)):

```
- name: reset ssh connection to allow user changes to affect 'current login user'
  meta: reset_connection
```

This will close the SSH connection, and force a new connection to be opened.